# Wordpress: adding an if-statement to a single post page ignores my section, but displays what is in the section

Tags: php, css, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm sorry for the blurry title.

I have a custom post type called 'service'. 
single-service.php now always adds the same form (made in Contactform7) to each service in a nice section that looks a bit different than the rest of the page. This works fine, but I want to have a possibility to use different forms for different services, or to have a service without a form. 
I added a custom field with ACF (service_booking) to the service post type, where you can put the shortcode of the form you want, or leave it blank if that service doesn't need a form, so I added an if-statement to do that.

```
<div class="col-md-6  wow animated fadeInRight">
<?php
the_field('service_description');
?>


<?php $form = the_field('service_booking');
 if (!empty($form)) {
?>

<a href="#booking" class="btn btn-primary bookbutton">Book now</a>

  </div>
 </div> 
</div>
</section>

<section id="booknow">
 <div class="container"><div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
   <div class="book" id="booking">
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-12 wow animated fadeInUp text-center">
      <h2>Booking</h2>
     <hr></div>
    </div>
    <?php the_field('service_booking');?>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
</section>

<?php }
else{ ?>
    </div>
   </div>   
  </div>
 </section>
<?php };
```

So I want to hide the button that leads you to the form, when there is no form and just close the first section instead of adding a new section. I left out the code that came before that because it was not relevant.

Everything works fine when there is no form, but when there is a form, the button that goes to the form is not appearing, the h2 of the form is not appearing and the form is put in the first section, it somehow totally ignores the second section. When I take away the if-statement, those things are visible again so my css is actually working.

What am I doing wrong?

I tried different forms, but the same problem keeps appearing.
Here's a random form I used to test it:

```
<label> Je naam (verplicht)
[text* your-name] </label>

<label> Je e-mail (verplicht)
[email* your-email] </label>

<label> Onderwerp
[text your-subject] </label>

<label> Je bericht
[textarea your-message] </label>

[submit "Verzenden"]
```

The things that come after my form are all fine again, the footer is displayed well etc.

I hope that everything is clear. Who can help me with this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the ACF documentation `the_field` function displays the value of the field instead of returning it so you cannot assign it to a variable. You should use `get_field` function instead.

```
$form = get_field('service_booking');
```

Also you should double check the `div` elements to make sure you don't have an extra or missed close tag otherwise your website don't load correctly due to a HTML structure problem.